# Stringcomparison OrdinalIgnoreCase for true false values

Tags: c#, string-comparison, ordinal

Does this make sense? MyValue can be "true" or "false"

Should it not be Stringcomparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ?

```
MyValue.Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: `MyValue.ToLower().Equals("true")`

Comment: @AmenAyach: This is not correct. `ToLower` is culture-dependant and therefore shouldn't be used for comparisons that are *not* culture-dependant. Things like this can introduce hard to find bugs in localized applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your situation and how the rest of your program is crafted. From the docs  on [OrdinalCompareCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx)

> The StringComparer returned by the OrdinalIgnoreCase property treats the characters in the strings to compare as if they were converted to uppercase using the conventions of the invariant culture, and then performs a simple byte comparison that is independent of language. This is most appropriate when comparing strings that are generated programmatically or when comparing case-insensitive resources such as paths and filenames.

So basically, if the values are culture independent (generated progamatically, etc) use `OrdinalIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 4):

I would not do that. Just because a string is not equal to `"true"` does not mean it's equal to `"false"`. This is an easy way to let ugly bugs slip in. I think you should parse the string

```
bool value;
if(!Boolean.TryParse(MyValue, out value)) {
    // it did not parse
}
// it parsed
```

This is more likely to be correct, and it's more readable. Plus, culture issues just got swept under the rug.

Answer (score 2):

```
Bool.Parse
```

[looks better to me.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx)

Comment: Well, `TryParse`. Don't let vexing exceptions happen.

Comment: In general yes but, as stated, the value can only be "true" or "false", so otherwsie would be exceptional. I wouldn't want to suppress that. If the OP has a way to handle it they should use `TryParse`

Comment: Right, so instead check the return value from `TryParse` and handle accordingly.